# Loading a string from a config file in MFC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, configuration-files

I have installed Postgres database and I am trying to connect to it from C++ code (VC++). Instead of passing hard-coded values to the Connect function (*edit: `PQconnectdb`?*), I would like to write a config file and read the values and send it to connect function.

How can I do it in vc++? Please help me.

```
CString Connect= _T("host=x.x.x.x port=5432 dbname=xxxxxx user=cdfvv password=hccjjj");
```

Instead of assigning value like this, I would like to write a config and process it.

Comment: What "`Connect` function"? Are you using libpq? C# and nPgSQL? ODBC? ADO / ADO.NET? Entity Framework? Details please. Also, an application config file doesn't seem to have much to do with PostgreSQL. Finally - why PostgreSQL 9.1 for new code?

Comment: yes i am using PQConnect function to connect to database which will have input string Connect as PQConnect(Connect) where connect is _T("host=x.x.x.x port=5432 dbname=xxxxxx user=cdfvv password=hccjjj");

Comment: As far as I can tell, `CString` is an MFC C++ class that can be implicitly converted to `const char *`. Assuming you are using C++ and libpq, then I guess you must mean that you are calling [libpq's `PQconnectdb` function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html). So you need to load the string from whatever config file you're using and pass it to `PQconnectdb`. It doesn't seem to be anything to do with PostgreSQL; this seems to be basic Windows API / MFC programming.

Comment: I have edited your question with my best guess as to what you are actually trying to ask.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/tour and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to get more out of Stack Overflow in future.

Answer (score 2):

(*I have edited your question with my best guess as to what you are actually trying to ask.*)

MFC provides the [`CWinApp::GetProfileString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62txabd8(v=vs.80).aspx) and [`CWinApp::SetProfileString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c2w6z4k(v=vs.80).aspx) methods, which abstract configuration to use an ini file or the registry. If you're using MFC, which it looks like you are, you should use these methods.

Otherwise, on Windows, consider using [the win32 Registry APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724875%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which is the normal way to store application configuration on Windows.

Or use an XML configuration file if you prefer; see [the manual for MSXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763742%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Alternately, there are numerous 3rd party libraries for parsing and storing configuration files in various formats, including `.ini`-style.

---

Personally I recommend that you do not use MFC, which I am guessing you are using based on your use of the `CString` class (?). IMO MFC is obsolete. Use plain C++ if you're writing a console application. If you're writing a GUI app, consider using Qt, or make your life easier by using C# and WinForms.

---

(By the way: I've never written an MFC application as I only work on cross-platform applications. I just did a few Google searches.)